# Flush file buffers in on non-Windows platforms

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have a logging component that uses a TByteStream for storing log contents and TFileStream for writing them to disk periodically. I need to ensure after writing to the file stream the file is updated immediately. So far I know only of FlushFileBuffers(), a Windows-specific function for that. How to do it on other supported by XE8 platforms?

Comment: You'll need platform specific for each platform that you target.

Comment: I get it, maybe I worded it confusing, I just don't know the necessary functions.

Comment: We don't know the platforms. It might be better to do them one at a time.

Comment: I wanted it for all currently supported by XE8 platforms.

Comment: I guess you could try closing the file stream. I belive this should force the data from buffer to be written directly to the hard drive. If this works, then it might not be a bad idea to check what code is called on closing of file stream to perhaps duplicate that in a special method of your own.

Comment: @SilverWarior Closing allows other parties to lock for writing. Better is to flush.

Comment: @ZzZombo What if I know the answer for two out of the three other platforms? I guess I cannot answer then. You are actually asking three questions here.

Comment: Sorry then. Feel free to answer what you know. But do you want me to open a separate question for each platform or what?

Comment: Partial answers are not encouraged here. So to play by the rules we would be expected to answer all your questions. I cannot do that and so cannot answer. That's why the site encourages you to ask one question at a time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm aware that closing file could lead to other application on gaining the lock on file. But main reason why I have recommended this is because I was hoping that TFileStream destructor might be calling some special code that could be reproduced in order to force the buffer to be flushed before closing the file. But as I realized later when I got to my development machine it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RTL has no function for flushing a file without closing it.  You have to use platform-specific functions instead.  On Windows, `TFileStream` uses the Win32 `CreateFile()` function to open/create a file, so you can use `FlushFileBuffers()` to flush it.  On other platforms, `TFileStream` uses the POSIX `open()` function to open/create a file, so you can use the POSIX `fsync()` function to flush it.

Try this:

```
uses
  ...
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  , Winapi.Windows
  {$ELSE}
  , Posix.Unistd
  {$ENDIF}
  ;

...

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
FlushFileBuffers(MyFileStream.Handle);
{$ELSE}
fsync(Integer(MyFileStream.Handle));
{$ENDIF}
```